# Generate permutations of Javascript object keys/values

Tags: javascript, algorithm, statistics, permutation

I need to create a nested hierarchy of options. The options are keys on an array with several sub-options as nested objects.

I need to generate a nested hierarchy from this object.

Starting with an object like this:

```
const starterObject = {
    id1: {
        1: { value: "A" },
        2: { value: "B" },
        3: { value: "C" },
    },
    id2: {
        1: { value: 10 },
        2: { value: 20 },
    },
};
```

I need to end up with an object of permutations like this:

```
const permutations2 = {
    1: [{ value: "A" }, { value: 10 }],
    2: [{ value: "A" }, { value: 20 }],
    3: [{ value: "B" }, { value: 10 }],
    4: [{ value: "B" }, { value: 20 }],
    5: [{ value: "C" }, { value: 10 }],
    6: [{ value: "C" }, { value: 20 }],
};
```

I tried something like this:

```js
const starterObject = {
    id1: {
        1: { value: "A" },
        2: { value: "B" },
        3: { value: "C" },
    },
    id2: {
        1: { value: 10 },
        2: { value: 20 },
    },
};


const permutationMatrix = [];

Object.keys(starterObject["id1"]).forEach(key2 =>
  Object.keys(starterObject["id2"]).forEach(key1 =>
    permutationMatrix.push([
      starterObject["id1"][key2],
      starterObject["id2"][key1],
    ])
  )
);

console.log(permutationMatrix)
```

But the problem is that the keys are hardcoded. The actual object will have 1-5 keys (id1 - id5) and any number of nested objects.

I think this will require recursion, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Which object will drive the loop?

Comment: Loop over `Object.keys( startObject )` itself instead of over `Object.keys(starterObject["id1"])` so you can use `starterObject[ id ]`. Also, if you can change the input object, use an actual array instead of an object with keys 1 to 5 and save yourself some trouble. `{ 1:"a", 2:"b", 3:"c"}` is almost the same as `[ "a", "b", "c" ]`. Ignore this last part if 1 to 6 as keys are just an example and the real data does not contain consecutive numbers.

Comment: For other reasons, the keys need to be integers starting from 1.

Comment: It's starting with id1 and going down the list.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce, entries, and values can help and there is no need for recursion.

```js
const starterObject = {
    id1: {
        1: { value: "A" },
        2: { value: "B" },
        3: { value: "C" },
    },
    id2: {
        1: { value: 10 },
        2: { value: 20 },
    },
    id3: {
        1: { value: 100 }
    }
};

var entries = Object.entries(starterObject)
var out = entries.reduce((arr, group) => {
  const itms = Object.values(group)[1]
  const vals =  Object.values(itms)
  // if first time, set up the initial arrays with first set of data
  if (!arr.length) {
    return vals.map(v => [v])
  }
  // after first one, we will just loop over the arrays
  // and start adding the next set of data to each one
  return arr.reduce((updated, curr) => {
    vals.forEach(val => {
      // make copy so we are not adding data to the reference
      const copy = curr.slice()
      copy.push(val)      
      updated.push(copy)
    })
    return updated
  }, [])
}, [])

console.log(JSON.stringify(out))
```

Comment: Great! That produces the result I was looking for. Thanks. I'm not sure I understand this `return vals.map(v => [v])`. What does `[v]` return?

Comment: just changes `[{},{},{}]` to `[[{}],[{}],[{}]]`

Comment: It is the same thing as `function(v) { return [v] }` or `function(v) { var arr = []; arr.push(v); return arr }`

Comment: How would I calculate the expected number of resulting permutations? Let's say the starter object has 5 ids (id1...id5) and each id has 3 sub-objects. This yields 162 permutations. What's the math behind this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursion for this. Your input/output format is somewhat peculiar with its array-like objects, with keys starting at 1. So for that I would suggest a separate wrapper function, which only takes care of such format conversions.

I had a go at a functional approach, creating separate functions for each of the callbacks needed in the process:

```js
const clone = o => ({...o});
const prefixer = item => arr => [item, ...arr].map(clone);
const merger = arr => item => arr.map(prefixer(item));
const extender = group => res => group.flatMap(merger(res));
// The recursive function based on standard array format
const cross = (group, ...rest) => group ? extender(group)(cross(...rest)) : [[]];
// For dealing with the unconventional input/output format: 
const baseOne = (x, i) => [i+1, x];
const generatePermutations = obj =>
    Object.fromEntries(cross(...Object.values(obj).map(Object.values)).map(baseOne));

// Sample data & call
const starterObject = {
    id1: {
        1: { value: "A" },
        2: { value: "B" },
        3: { value: "C" },
    },
    id2: {
        1: { value: 10 },
        2: { value: 20 },
    },
};

const permutations = generatePermutations(starterObject);

console.log(permutations);
```